# Is it good to save database connections in xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net, configuration, saving-data

I am on a general scenario of deploying my vb.net database application on my client's computer.

Thinking of future problem of changing the database connection setting, i am planning to store it in a normal xml file in the app directory so that where ever it is installed, in order to make database configuration i only need to make change to that file and my program runs smoothly.

So is this idea of storing database connection setting to xml config file in app directory or is there any other better idea?

I am planning it for vb.net winforms applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 2.0 or later, you can use a separate file to store general settings and separate them from what's on the main .config file, like:

```
<appSettings file="myotherfile.config" />
```

You can then update just that one file.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.

Note that under ASP.NET, for web.config files, a change to the appSettings file does not trigger a reload of the whole web.config.

Comment: is it same for vb.net winforms applications too... sorry i couldn't mention it prior

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You add the section to your app.config, then create the file and drop it in the same directory. Then when you get any setting through the ConfigurationManager it will be retrieved from there.